# Redirect rules for .htaccess with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I have a PHP script dynamically generating content from a database based on queries. The user might do a search from a text box for the username "mark". The content is provided by PHP at www.domain.com/?username=mark, though I would like the user to see the serving URL as www.domain.com/username/mark.html. Similarly, the user might search by a profile (integer). The content is generated at www.domain.com/?profile=2. I would like the user to see the serving URL as www.domain.com/profile/2.html. Is this doable?

Here's my .htaccess file:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^username/([^/]*)\.html$ /?username=$1 [L]
 RewriteRule ^realname/([^/]*)\.html$ /?realname=$1 [L]
 RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)\.html$ /?profile=$1 [L]
```

Mod_rewrite is enabled but this file doesn't appear to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be working, maybe it's not executed at all. You can try to make a typo and see if Apache gives a 500 response.

Beside that you can try to use the following htaccess. Added index.php, to ensure the right file is called.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^username/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?username=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^realname/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?realname=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?profile=$1 [L]
```